# Vue.js transition mode not working?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am currently working on a slider component but it seems that my transition mode is not working. I have used:

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
```

To my understanding this should force the element going out to first complete it's entire animation before the element in is being rendered.

This is an example of my slider component:

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KfMMcLvpUA6LGOFL3vM

I could fix it by overlaying images absolute but that is obviously not something that I want to do when there could be a neater solution.

The transition CSS is included in the header of the index page:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I have it up the as easily usable as possible, if somebody could take a look that would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding that one transition will complete before another starts is wrong. It might be true if you were changing out an element within a single `transition` tag, but it is not true when each element is wrapped in its own `transition` tag.

The easiest thing you could do is use `setTimeout` to make the assignment of the next `activeSlide` wait for the transition.

```
    methods: {
        prevSlide() {
            const nextSlide = this.activeSlide === this.firstSlide ? this.lastSlide : this.activeSlide - 1;
            this.activeSlide = null;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.activeSlide = nextSlide;
            }, 500);
        },
        nextSlide() {
            const nextSlide = this.activeSlide === this.lastSlide ? this.firstSlide : this.activeSlide + 1;
            this.activeSlide = null;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.activeSlide = nextSlide;
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

That requires that your timeout value and your CSS transition length be kept in sync.

Somewhat more work would be to use the [transition hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) to emit events when a leave transition started and ended.

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in" @leave="transitionStarted" @after-leave="transitionComplete">
```

You would catch them in the top-level code, (not in slider, because slot events don't propagate to the slot container)

```
<slide src="http://lorempixel.com/196/196" alt="" @transition-started="holdUp" @transition-complete="okGo"></slide>
```

In the handlers (`holdUp` and `okGo`) you would set a boolean data item that you would pass to `slider` as a prop. In `slider`, `nextSlide` and `prevSlide` would calculate what the next value of `activeSlide` will be, but will not set it. It would get set when the prop indicated that the transition was finished.